# How to change a value from in a django model while its foreign key?

Tags: python, django, database, model

Cart_Items , Cart , Order models .i want for my shopping website , that after a ordering a product , a value increased , but i cant access it .

i tried to get it by 
   pr=Products.objects.all()
   ci=Cart_Items.filter(product_id=pr)

my models.py:

order model:

```
   class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_id  = models.CharField(  max_length=120,default="ABC",unique=True)
    cart  =   models.ForeignKey(Cart,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    statu = models.CharField(max_length=120,choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default="Started")
```

product model:

```
    class Products(models.Model):
     title           =   models.CharField(max_length=250)
     order_qty       =   models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Cart_Items model:

```
     class Cart_Items(models.Model):
          cart      =  models.ForeignKey('Cart',null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
         product_id = models.ForeignKey(Products,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

cart model :

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    total      = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    timestamp  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
    date       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=True)
    isPaid     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

my views.py:

```
    def add(request):
        cart_items=Cart_Items.objects.all()
         for item in cart_items:
            print(item.product_id.order_qty)
            item.product_id.order_qty +=1
         render(request,"home.html",{})
```

i want after ordering a product , order_qty , increased , how can i do that ?
i must do it by Cart_items ? or there is another ways ?
plz help.

Comment: Usually one does *not* save the `order_quantity` in a field. This is calculated by the number of related `CartItem`s.

Comment: You should rename your models to use PascalCase and in singular, for example `CartItem`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call save method, after you change a value:

```
 def add(request):
    cart_items=Cart_Items.objects.all()
     for item in cart_items:
        print(item.product_id.order_qty)
        item.product_id.order_qty +=1
        item.save()
     render(request,"home.html",{})
```

Or like @Wilem said, you can count the quantity by the number of all the items in the order:

```
   Order.objects.all().count
```

Comment: hi , i dont want to add Order quantity , i want add the order_quantity from Products model. but when i do the Order , i only access selected items in cart by Cart items

Comment: So, you mean that you wanna to grab all the quantity of the products and increase them? Try overriding the save method of the Order, Products or Cart items. With this, when you save the model you want, you can get the model and do whatever you want with him or another one.

Comment: here is the senario : after i added 3 products to my shopping cart (for example) ,this items are added to my cart_items, no after i don the order process , i want to add 1 to the field of my products model (this is use to know wich products buyed must) . i have a field for this in my Products model and i want it to increase to 1 for each item in Cart_Items Model(my products).. How Can I do That ? Can Any One Make An Example Code For Me ?